# NSURL passing with one argument

Tags: iphone, xcode

```
NSString *myString = @"1994";
    NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"data=%@",myString];

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://nyxmyx.com/Kinkey/KinkeyPHP/lastid2.php/?data=%@",myString];
    NSLog(@"URL%@",url);

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSLog(@"postDATA%@",postData);
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    NSLog(@"postLENGTH%@",postLength);
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSError *error1 = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error1];
    NSString *string;
    if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
        {
        string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];
        UIAlertView *alert1=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"alert1" message:string delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert1 show];
        }
```

I am new to objective c. When I am sending NSURL with an argument it is give error as "Too many arguments expects 1 have 2 "How do I change my url with one argument?

Comment: You don't have to `alloc init NSError` as you are passing it's reference. `NSError *error = nil` is the correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have corrected few things and tested your code, it should be fine now:

```
NSString *myString = @"1994";
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"data=%@",myString];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://nyxmyx.com/Kinkey/KinkeyPHP/lastid2.php/?data=%@",myString]];
NSLog(@"URL%@",url);

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSLog(@"postDATA%@",postData);
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSLog(@"postLENGTH%@",postLength);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSError *error1 = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error1];
NSString *string;
if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
    {
    string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];
    UIAlertView *alert1=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"alert1" message:string delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert1 show];
    }
```

Response from above call:

1995,prabu,1231231233,antab,8080808080,1360738531881.jpg,No
1996,prabu,1231231233,antab,8080808080,1361013972284.jpg,No
1997,prabu,1231231233,antab,8080808080,1360844505212.jpg,No
1998,josh,0417697070,null,+61420224346,1361160944442.jpg,No
1999,josh,0417697070,null,+61420224346,1356047464383.jpg,No
2000,josh,0417697070,null,+61420224346,1361160816141.jpg,No
2001,wooza,0420224346,J Wratt ,+61417697070,2013-55-1803-55-54.jpg,No
2002,wooza,0420224346,J Wratt ,+61417697070,2013-56-1803-56-17.jpg,No
2003,testing,9894698946,ggh hjj,9894598945,2013-11-1811-11-40.jpg,Yes

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://nyxmyx.com/Kinkey/KinkeyPHP/lastid2.php/?data=%@",myString];
```

with

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://nyxmyx.com/Kinkey/KinkeyPHP/lastid2.php/?data=%@",myString]];
```

Comment: I am getting error as unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8f85860 after postLength